# Issue related to architecture design

Tags: .net, architecture

I have design problem on which I hope to get help.

Say I have a domain entity say "User", "Institution".

This "User" can be registered to various "services" for example "accounting or library". I created a abstract class of "ServiceRegistration" and "User" has list of these service registrations. These services are nothing but the modules that will be plugged in as component in future. So when my Library component is complete, I can plugin into my system. The Library component will have say "LibraryServiceRegistration" class which will be stored in "User" -> "ServiceRegistration" list. "User" is unaware of this "LibraryServiceRegistration" and thus becomes extendible. The library component is currently aware of "User" so that it can store the "LibraryServiceRegistration" information in "User".

But now say I created a new components "Accounting" which is applicable to "User" and "Institution". My accounting component will have "AccountingServiceRegistration" stored in  "User" -> "ServiceRegistration" for every user and  "Institution" -> "ServiceRegistration" for every institution.

I wish to isolate "Accounting" component such that I can make it configurable to which domain entity it can provide service too. So currently it can provide service to "User" and "Institution" in future without altering th code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So clearly some piece of code in your system needs to know about both services and entities.  The question is really which piece of code should take care of that.

Here are the options that I see:

- entity defines which services it can take (undesirable according to your post)
- service defines which entities it supports (possible)
- service registration class defines which entities it supports (this could also be good)
- a new class (factory?) handles the matching (could work if you are already using a factory)

All of this becomes a lot easier if all of your domain entities implement a common interface.

My recommendation would be to have an abstract method on the base Service that lists the entities that it supports.  Each Service would then declare what entities it supports.  Furthermore, whatever method on Service creates a new registration against an entity would be able to validate the entity type.

I hope this helps